# Django app on Heroku, deployed successfully but could not be served

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have built a simple blog app with Django by following a video and deployed it to Heroku by following another video. 
The app works fine locally, but it is not working online. 
Heroku gives me this error message:

This app has no process types yet

Add a Procfile to your app in order to define its process types.

I had already added a Proclife created with Notepad with these contents:

web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi

But how can I add another Procfile to an app already deployed to Heroku?
Where should I place it?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's correct. It required file 'Procfile' in the project root directory. I have created one with below content

```
web: gunicorn <your-app.wsgi> -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 10
```

And followed the below link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile where everything is mentioned to deploy the code to heroku.
Its been long time for me working with heroku that too with test app so I am not sure if it got changed after that. But I think just following the link will work just fine.

Comment: How will I add the updated Procfile to the deployed app? Will I have to delete and redeploy the app?

Comment: Possibly. it would be handy using `git` command. But if not then I think just modifying the file content and running the deployment command will work. No need to recreate file as it wont make any difference.